# Create React App with bootstrap css

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, webpack

I'm using Create React App and want to include bootstrap css into my project. I saw the instructions for including React Bootstrap on the create-react-app github, but I'm looking for just regular bootstrap, not React Bootstrap.

I've installed bootstrap through npm and am including it inside of my index.js file like so

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
```

This seems to partially work when I run the start script. The fonts appear to be using bootstrap, but that's it, i.e. none of the other Bootstrap CSS appears to work.

I get the following error when tryng to build

```
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module '[object Object]' in /Users/username/Sites/Learning/modular
/src
```

I'm guessing this has to do with the fonts. I'm having some difficulty modifying the webpack config to allow the bootstrap fonts.

Has anyone been able to achieve this?

I'm using more or less the same webpack config create-react-app ships with. I did, however, modify the CSS loader so that it can load SASS and is capable of SASS/CSS modules. I've tested that simply requiring an entire stylesheet without using CSS modules still works.

```
var autoprefixer = require("autoprefixer");
var webpack = require("webpack");
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
var CaseSensitivePathsPlugin = require("case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin");
var InterpolateHtmlPlugin = require("react-dev-utils/InterpolateHtmlPlugin");
var WatchMissingNodeModulesPlugin = require(
  "react-dev-utils/WatchMissingNodeModulesPlugin"
);
var getClientEnvironment = require("./env");
var paths = require("./paths");

// Webpack uses `publicPath` to determine where the app is being served from.
// In development, we always serve from the root. This makes config easier.
var publicPath = "/";
// `publicUrl` is just like `publicPath`, but we will provide it to our app
// as %PUBLIC_URL% in `index.html` and `process.env.PUBLIC_URL` in JavaScript.
// Omit trailing slash as %PUBLIC_PATH%/xyz looks better than %PUBLIC_PATH%xyz.
var publicUrl = "";
// Get environment variables to inject into our app.
var env = getClientEnvironment(publicUrl);

// This is the development configuration.
// It is focused on developer experience and fast rebuilds.
// The production configuration is different and lives in a separate file.
module.exports = {
  // You may want 'eval' instead if you prefer to see the compiled output in DevTools.
  // See the discussion in https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/343.
  devtool: "cheap-module-source-map",
  // These are the "entry points" to our application.
  // This means they will be the "root" imports that are included in JS bundle.
  // The first two entry points enable "hot" CSS and auto-refreshes for JS.
  entry: [
    // Include an alternative client for WebpackDevServer. A client's job is to
    // connect to WebpackDevServer by a socket and get notified about changes.
    // When you save a file, the client will either apply hot updates (in case
    // of CSS changes), or refresh the page (in case of JS changes). When you
    // make a syntax error, this client will display a syntax error overlay.
    // Note: instead of the default WebpackDevServer client, we use a custom one
    // to bring better experience for Create React App users. You can replace
    // the line below with these two lines if you prefer the stock client:
    // require.resolve('webpack-dev-server/client') + '?/',
    // require.resolve('webpack/hot/dev-server'),
    require.resolve("react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient"),
    // We ship a few polyfills by default:
    require.resolve("./polyfills"),
    // Finally, this is your app's code:
    paths.appIndexJs
    // We include the app code last so that if there is a runtime error during
    // initialization, it doesn't blow up the WebpackDevServer client, and
    // changing JS code would still trigger a refresh.
  ],
  output: {
    // Next line is not used in dev but WebpackDevServer crashes without it:
    path: paths.appBuild,
    // Add /* filename */ comments to generated require()s in the output.
    pathinfo: true,
    // This does not produce a real file. It's just the virtual path that is
    // served by WebpackDevServer in development. This is the JS bundle
    // containing code from all our entry points, and the Webpack runtime.
    filename: "static/js/bundle.js",
    // This is the URL that app is served from. We use "/" in development.
    publicPath: publicPath
  },
  resolve: {
    // This allows you to set a fallback for where Webpack should look for modules.
    // We read `NODE_PATH` environment variable in `paths.js` and pass paths here.
    // We use `fallback` instead of `root` because we want `node_modules` to "win"
    // if there any conflicts. This matches Node resolution mechanism.
    // https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/253
    fallback: paths.nodePaths,
    // These are the reasonable defaults supported by the Node ecosystem.
    // We also include JSX as a common component filename extension to support
    // some tools, although we do not recommend using it, see:
    // https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/290
    extensions: [".js", ".json", ".jsx", ""],
    alias: {
      // Support React Native Web
      // https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/08/a-glimpse-into-the-future-with-react-native-for-web/
      "react-native": "react-native-web"
    }
  },

  module: {
    // First, run the linter.
    // It's important to do this before Babel processes the JS.
    preLoaders: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        loader: "eslint",
        include: paths.appSrc
      }
    ],
    loaders: [
      // ** ADDING/UPDATING LOADERS **
      // The "url" loader handles all assets unless explicitly excluded.
      // The `exclude` list *must* be updated with every change to loader extensions.
      // When adding a new loader, you must add its `test`
      // as a new entry in the `exclude` list for "url" loader.

      // "url" loader embeds assets smaller than specified size as data URLs to avoid requests.
      // Otherwise, it acts like the "file" loader.
      {
        exclude: [/\.html$/, /\.(js|jsx)$/, /\.css$/, /\.json$/, /\.svg$/],
        loader: "url",
        query: {
          limit: 10000,
          name: "static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]"
        }
      },
      // Process JS with Babel.
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        include: paths.appSrc,
        loader: "babel",
        query: {
          // This is a feature of `babel-loader` for webpack (not Babel itself).
          // It enables caching results in ./node_modules/.cache/babel-loader/
          // directory for faster rebuilds.
          cacheDirectory: true
        }
      },
      // "postcss" loader applies autoprefixer to our CSS.
      // "css" loader resolves paths in CSS and adds assets as dependencies.
      // "style" loader turns CSS into JS modules that inject <style> tags.
      // In production, we use a plugin to extract that CSS to a file, but
      // in development "style" loader enables hot editing of CSS.
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loaders: [
          "style?sourceMap",
          "css?modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[path]___[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]",
          "resolve-url",
          "sass?sourceMap"
        ]
      },
      // JSON is not enabled by default in Webpack but both Node and Browserify
      // allow it implicitly so we also enable it.
      {
        test: /\.json$/,
        loader: "json"
      },
      // "file" loader for svg
      // {
      //   test: /\.svg$/,
      //   loader: "file",
      //   query: {
      //     name: "static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]"
      //   }
      // },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg|woff|woff2)$/,
        loader: "url"
      },
      {
        test: /\.(eot|ttf|wav|mp3)$/,
        loader: "file"
      }

      // ** STOP ** Are you adding a new loader?
      // Remember to add the new extension(s) to the "url" loader exclusion list.
    ]
  },

  // We use PostCSS for autoprefixing only.
  postcss: function() {
    return [
      autoprefixer({
        browsers: [
          ">1%",
          "last 4 versions",
          "Firefox ESR",
          "not ie < 9" // React doesn't support IE8 anyway
        ]
      })
    ];
  },
  plugins: [
    // Makes some environment variables available in index.html.
    // The public URL is available as %PUBLIC_URL% in index.html, e.g.:
    // <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico">
    // In development, this will be an empty string.
    new InterpolateHtmlPlugin(env.raw),
    // Generates an `index.html` file with the <script> injected.
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      inject: true,
      template: paths.appHtml
    }),
    // Makes some environment variables available to the JS code, for example:
    // if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') { ... }. See `./env.js`.
    new webpack.DefinePlugin(env.stringified),
    // This is necessary to emit hot updates (currently CSS only):
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    // Watcher doesn't work well if you mistype casing in a path so we use
    // a plugin that prints an error when you attempt to do this.
    // See https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/240
    new CaseSensitivePathsPlugin(),
    // If you require a missing module and then `npm install` it, you still have
    // to restart the development server for Webpack to discover it. This plugin
    // makes the discovery automatic so you don't have to restart.
    // See https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/186
    new WatchMissingNodeModulesPlugin(paths.appNodeModules)
  ],
  // Some libraries import Node modules but don't use them in the browser.
  // Tell Webpack to provide empty mocks for them so importing them works.
  node: {
    fs: "empty",
    net: "empty",
    tls: "empty"
  }
};
```

My current thought is this has to do with the font files Bootstrap uses. The config doesn't seem equipped to handle ttf, woff,woff2, or svg files. (svg's seem to get placed into a static folder which maybe messes up the paths?)

Comment: Can you include the config?

Comment: I updated it @Chris. I'm using *almost* the same config create react app ships with, but would appreciate any help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. create-react-app can require and use bootstrap inside of the JavaScript right out of the box.

My issue is that I also added CSS modules. Webpack was trying to load bootstrap using CSS modules, and it probably had issues because of fonts being required. Requiring other global CSS doesn't produce this issue.

I resolved the issue by adding a rule to my webpack config for CSS filenames ending in `.global.css` and altered the rule for CSS modules to ignore any CSS with a file name ending in `.global.css`.

I copied the Bootstrap CSS and font file and put them into an assets folder inside of my project directory. I renamed bootstrap.min.css to be bootstrap.min.global.css. I required it from the assets folder.

This is the best solution I've found for mixing CSS modules with global css in webpack.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use relative Webpack import of NPM modules. `~`

```
import '~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
```

Comment: That gives me this error 

Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module '~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.
css' in /Users/chriseckenrode/Sites/Learning/modular/src

Comment: Could you please check that the path is OK? Do you have properly install bootstrap in `node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css`?